# sqlalchemy cannot create URL object 'NameError: name 'URL' is not defined'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

A couple weeks ago I was able to create a connection to SQL server using the following lines.

```
import sqlalchemy
connection_string = 'Driver={SQL Server};' 'Server=someserver;' 'Database=some_db;' 'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})

engine = create_engine(connection_url)
```

Today I went to run it again and I got the following error

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [8], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 import sqlalchemy
      2 connection_string = 'Driver={SQL Server};' 'Server=someserver;' 'Database=some_db;' 'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
----> 3 connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})
      5 engine = create_engine(connection_url)

NameError: name 'URL' is not defined
```

I created a new env and reinstalled all of the packages I was using. That did not help. Can anyone help me understand why I can't create the URL object? I tried using make_url and got a separate error below

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [9], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 import sqlalchemy
      2 connection_string = 'Driver={SQL Server};' 'Server=someserver;' 'Database=some_db;' 'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
----> 3 connection_url = sqlalchemy.make_url("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})
      5 engine = create_engine(connection_url)

AttributeError: module 'sqlalchemy' has no attribute 'make_url'
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? I'm perplexed because this worked fine the last time I ran this.

Comment: It's `sqlalchemy.engine.URL.create()` https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.URL

Comment: Or `from sqlalchemy.engine import URL` followed by `connection_url = URL.create(…)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that both `URL` and `make_url` moved to `sqlalchemy.engine.url` in SQLAlchemy ^2.0.0

Comment: I can import both from `sqlalchemy.engine` (the names are exposed in `sqlalchemy.engine.__init__`).

Comment: Yes, it seems that at runtime python finds the names under `.engine` just fine. Yet at typechecking mypy cannot. So to avoid squigglies, one can import them from `.engine.url`, and it will work and mypy will also be satisfied.

Comment: tbh mypy (0.991) works for me with the imports from `engine`, for example `url: URL = URL.create(...)`.